# Execute formula next 10 rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a `concat_custom` script I'd like to execute 10 rows at a time.

For example, in this sheet:

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O1rZUstDNSXPdUVXvaDfPO4rAQs2cJWHimfGxbddtNU/edit#gid=450240458

**Custom function:**

```
function concat_custom(s, array) {
    array = conformToOneDimensionalArray(array);

    return array.filter(function (value) {
      return value != "";
    }).join("-");
}

function conformToOneDimensionalArray(value) {
  if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
    value = [value];
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(value[0])) {
    value = value.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b);
    });
  }

  return value;
}
```

I'd like column C to have text `Ted-John` and not `=concat_custom("-",A1:B1)` so column C will be independent of `A & B`. How can I process say 10 rows at a time in this example?

I'd like to be able to process 10 rows every minute through timed triggers. So it checks the last row then continues from there.

Comment: ``=A1:A40&"-"&B1:B40``?

Comment: @TheMaster I'd like to have it permanent where if the referenced cell changes, the result column `C` does not change

Comment: If you are not required to use the custom function, how about directly put the result values you want using Google Apps Script by the time-driven trigger? I think that this will be simple script. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike you got it, I'll be using the time-driven trigger to trigger 10 rows per minute (because the custom function API I will be using has a 10 query per minute limit).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function withadash() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var nextrow=getNextRowInColumn3();
  if(nextrow>0) {    
    var rg=sh.getRange(nextrow,1,10,3);
    var vA=rg.getValues()
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      vA[i][2]=vA[i][0]+'-'+vA[i][1];
    }
    rg.setValues(vA);
  }
}

function getNextRowInColumn3() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][0]) {
      return i+1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```